What is the difference between an algorithm and a model in statistics and data analysis?
A student asked me, "What is the difference between a model and an algorithm?"
I explained the difference between a model and an algorithm as follows.
In my opinion, a model is a mathematical or probabilistic structure that is assumed to represent the underlying process that the data follows. In other words, it is a mathematical-probabilistic structure or expression that is assumed to be followed by the data. An algorithm, on the other hand, is a computational procedure used to solve a specific problem or perform a task.
To illustrate the difference between the two, consider the following example:
Imagine a Gaussian mixture model is fitted to the data and we want to use MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimation). When estimating the parameters of that model, we might use the EM (Expectation-Maximization) algorithm or another algorithm. Therefore, the primary goal of algorithms is to solve computational equations that arise from modeling the data. In other words, algorithms are used in data analysis to perform computations related to mathematical and statistical models.
To sum up, regression is a model, while EM is an algorithm.
Then another student asked me whether the average of observations is an algorithm or a model. What about MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimation),bayesian approach for parameters estimation, Decision Trees, or Gradient Descent?
Is there a precise definition that distinguishes an algorithm from a model?
In response to this student, I said that I will provide a detailed answer to your question later!
Specifically, what are the correct answers concerning mean of observations, MLE and Bayesian inference? I'm not quite sure about these aspects.

A model is a set of assumptions and their logical implications.  An algorithm is a set of steps we use to compute$^\dagger$ things coming out of the model (in some appropriate representation).

$^\dagger$ And even the notion of "computing" an answer is quite interesting in its own right, since this may involve stipulation of what constitutes a "solution".

Direct and informative.

The problem is that the terms are not used fully consistently in the literature. Particularly some people in machine learning call a model what we would call an algorithm. We could also talk about "methods" and may or may not distinguish them from algorithms. By and large I agree with your explanation (and with @Ben's answer). Computing the average is a method, but one could also call it one step algorithm. I'd call MLE, the Bayesian approach, gradient descent and the like "approaches". They are general principles that aren't really models or algorithms. One may get away with calling MLE "method" but I'd rather use that word for a specific MLE, not for the approach in general, or rather, it's a method for finding estimators, whereas the estimators themselves are methods for estimating from data.
The K-means method is defined by minimising the within cluster sum of squares. There are various algorithms to find a good minimum, and unless the data set is very small, none of them is guaranteed to find the global minimum, which can actually be seen to define the method. Some people call a specific algorithm "K-means" (in my view a method can be an algorithm but doesn't have to be). Also the EM-algorithm is a general principle and only its specific instances may be seen as algorithms. So there is confusion all around...
